# Grab ID from form array

Tags: php, forms, post, mysqli

I believe this is probably a very simple question, but since I'm just dealing with numbers, it sorta makes my brain hurt.

Below is my form with some lines removed due to being irrelevant to the question

```
$envList = $link->query("SELECT * FROM environments");
echo "<form action = 'editEnvOrderExec.php' method = 'post'>";
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'userID' value = '".$userID."'>"
while($row = $envList->fetch_assoc()){
    $eName = $row['name'];
    $dID = $row['displayID'];
    $eID = $row['id'];
    echo $eName.": <input type = 'text' name = 'eID[".$eID."]' value = '".$dID."'><BR>";
}
```

Upon submitting the `$_POST` looks like this

```
array(2) {
  ["userID"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["eID"]=>
  array(6) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

I need to take the values in the brackets, `[1][3][4][5][6][8]` and for each one have a mysql statement update the `displayID` with the value `[1][2][3][4][5][6]`. My problem is I can't figure out how to target each one...

NOTE: I know I need to sanitize values, as well as check if a display ID is already used and such, but this is just v0.1. Trying to get functionality down, then I can tackle those other issues

Comment: If you need them separately, you might use for keys: [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array-keys), for values: [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is if you're iterating over the loop using [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach):

```
$eID = $row['eID'];

foreach ($eID as $key => $value) {
    // here $key is the array key you're looking for.
}
```